# Cyrillic with TexStudio and JabRef

Tags: texstudio, cyrillic, jabref

I was not able with the help of Google to solve my problem yet. I have a reference from a Russian journal. That's why I entered the authors and journal title in cyrillic letters in JabRef. Now I run into problems when compiling the document with TeXStudio.

Does someone of you have experience with that?

My current encoding in JabRef is Cp1252 and after a lot of experimentation I stopped with the following packages:

```
\usepackage[russian,english]{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish,russian]{babel}
```

Comment: You should at least use UTF-8 as encoding in JabRef. However a minimal example, including the bib entry is necessary.

Comment: When I type in Cyrillic chars I just load `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,OT1]{fontenc}` and then I can change my keyboard layout and type directly in Cyrillic.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a) to use UTF-8 in your .bib file, b) use UTF-8 in latex, and c) use bibtex8 or biblatex (with biber) which can handle UTF-8 encoded .bib files (as bibtex CANNOT handle utf-8 encoded .bib files).