# JabRef and Cyrillic citation

Tags: pdftex, cyrillic, jabref

It is a similar question to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220457/cyrillic-with-texstudio-and-jabref). However, I already defined my file.bib as UTF-8 and also similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215459/biblatex-biber-and-non-latin-cyrillic-utf-8-names-part-ii?lq=1) but my biggest problem is that I **must** follow [ABNT](http://www.abntex.net.br/) and [my university's format](http://sourceforge.net/projects/normas-utf-tex/).

The file I have has an entry as such:

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.10.
% Encoding: UTF8
@Article{russian2002,
  Title                    = {Эпидемиология опухолей головного мозга: статистические факторы},
  Author                   = {Розуменко, ВД},
  Journal                  = {Український нейрохірургічний журнал},
  Year                     = {2002},
  Number                   = {3},
  Pages                    = {47--48},
  Volume                   = {1},

  Langid                   = {russian},
  Owner                    = {Rodrigo},
  Publisher                = {Національна академія медичних наук України, Інститут нейрохірургії ім. акад. АП Ромоданова, Українська Асоціація Нейрохірургів},
  Timestamp                = {2015.08.23}
}
```

Which is converted into this after running pdfLatex (through TexStudio):

```
\providecommand{\abntreprintinfo}[1]{%
 \citeonline{#1}}
\setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}\begin{thebibliography}{}
\providecommand{\abntrefinfo}[3]{}
\providecommand{\abntbstabout}[1]{}
\abntbstabout{1.52 }

\bibitem[Розуменко 2002]{russian2002}
\abntrefinfo{Розуменко}{Розуменко}{2002}
{Розуменко, . Эпидемиология опухолей
  головного мозга: статистические факторы.
\emph{Український нейрохірургічний журнал},
  Національна академія медичних наук
  України, Інститут нейрохірургії ім. акад.
  АП Ромоданова, Українська Асоціація
  Нейрохірургів, v.~1, n.~3, p. 47--48, 2002.}
```

And the compiler will give the same error as stated in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215459/biblatex-biber-and-non-latin-cyrillic-utf-8-names-part-ii?lq=1)

> ! LaTeX Error: Command \CYRF unavailable in encoding T1.

Unfortunately for me, there solution provided there does not work for me as when I try to use this:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,language=auto,autolang=other]{biblatex}
```

It returns those two errors:

> ! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
>
> ! Package biblatex Error: '\bibliographystyle' invalid.

Comment: Can you please come up with a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of your set-up? To me it seems you are already using another package for bibliographies, that is why you cannot simply use `biblatex`.

Comment: @moewe I am a newbie in Latex and from what I understand the [class](http://sourceforge.net/projects/normas-utf-tex/) that I have to use defines the `biblatex`, but I could not figure out where. I will try to make it and post it here tough.

Comment: OK, but please make sure to only paste the relevant code and not dump the entirely file here. If you are already using `biblatex` that is great. Just come up with a short file, using your document class that shows you citing and subsequently everything falling apart, see [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) for that, please.

Comment: Wouldn't a transliteration help your readers more than reporting the citation in the Cyrillic script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some juggles for keeping the ABNT class happy; the initials of the author's name must be treated specially because of how the bibliography style chops them.

Here I use `filecontents` just to keep the example self-contained.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{russian2002,
  Title     = {\textcyrillic{Эпидемиология опухолей головного мозга: статистические факторы}},
  Author    = {\SORTNOOP{Rozumenko}{\textcyrillic{Розуменко}}, {\VD}},
  Journal   = {\textcyrillic{Український нейрохірургічний журнал}},
  Year      = {2002},
  Number    = {3},
  Pages     = {47--48},
  Volume    = {1},
  Langid    = {russian},
  Owner     = {Rodrigo},
  Publisher = {\textcyrillic{Національна академія медичних наук України, 
               Інститут нейрохірургії ім. акад. АП Ромоданова, 
               Українська Асоціація Нейрохірургів}},
  Timestamp = {2015.08.23}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[
  article,
  11pt,
  oneside,
  a4paper,
  russian,
  brazil,
  sumario=tradicional
]{abntex2}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{T2A}{\rmdefault}{cmr} % lmodern is bad for Cyrillic

\usepackage{lipsum} % para geração de dummy text

% ---
% Pacotes de citações
% ---
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}     % Paginas com as citações na bibl
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}   % Citações padrão ABNT
% ---

\titulo{Modelo Canônico de\\ Artigo científico com \abnTeX}
\autor{Equipe \abnTeX\thanks{\url{http://www.abntex.net.br/}} \and Lauro
César
Araujo\thanks{laurocesar@laurocesar.com}}
\local{Brasil}
\data{2015, v-1.9.5}

% informações do PDF
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
        %pagebackref=true,
        pdftitle={\@title}, 
        pdfauthor={\@author},
        pdfsubject={Modelo de artigo científico com abnTeX2},
        pdfcreator={LaTeX with abnTeX2},
        pdfkeywords={abnt}{latex}{abntex}{abntex2}{atigo científico}, 
        colorlinks=true,            % false: boxed links; true: colored links
        linkcolor=blue,             % color of internal links
        citecolor=blue,             % color of links to bibliography
        filecolor=magenta,              % color of file links
        urlcolor=blue,
        bookmarksdepth=4
}
\makeatother
% --- 

% ---
% compila o indice
% ---
\makeindex
% ---

% ---
% Altera as margens padrões
% ---
\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
% ---

% --- 
% Espaçamentos entre linhas e parágrafos 
% --- 

% O tamanho do parágrafo é dado por:
\setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}

% Controle do espaçamento entre um parágrafo e outro:
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}  % tente também \onelineskip

% Espaçamento simples
\SingleSpacing

% personal commands
\newcommand{\SORTNOOP}[2]{#2}
\newcommand{\VD}{\textcyrillic{\CYRV\CYRD}}

% ----
% Início do documento
% ----
\begin{document}

% Seleciona o idioma do documento (conforme pacotes do babel)
%\selectlanguage{english}
\selectlanguage{brazil}

% Retira espaço extra obsoleto entre as frases.
\frenchspacing 

\maketitle

\textual

\section*{Introdução}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introdução}

Este documento e seu código-fonte são exemplos de referência de uso da classe
\textsf{abntex2} e do pacote \textsf{abntex2cite}. O documento exemplifica a
elaboração de publicação periódica científica impressa produzida conforme a ABNT
NBR 6022:2003 \emph{Informação e documentação - Artigo em publicação periódica
científica impressa - Apresentação}.

Citação: \cite{russian2002}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

My impression is that a transliteration can be more helpful to your readers.

Comment: I wish, I could upvote this twice. Thank you!